# What happens if i try to split a string that cannot be split in python?

Tags: python

I'm running the following code to read a graph from a file.File contains the adjacency list in the format: each line will contain:vertex neighbour1 neighbour2...
Here I'm trying to put it into a dictionary adjacent.now if a node does not have a neighbor what happens with the line.split()? there will be only the vertex in that line.

```
  f=open('graph','r')
  for line in f:
      values=line.split()
      for x in values[1:]:
           adjacent[values[0]].append(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a list of *one* element. Your next line will loop over an empty slice:

```
>>> 'one_vertex\n'.split()
['one_vertex']
>>> 'one_vertex\n'.split()[1:]
[]
```

Comment: values[0] will contain vertex and values[1] will be an empty list?

Comment: shouldnt it flag an error saying it needs more than 1 value to unpack?

Comment: @user1614476: No, the *slice* `values[1:]` is an empty list. `values[1]` will throw an index error.

Comment: @user1614476: Where are you unpacking anything? Unpacking only happens when you assign from a list to a series of names; `value1, value2 = values`.